# How correctly compile a Java class using a classpath?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, classpath, javac

I have a Java Main class that use an external **.jar** library.

So I am trying to compile it putting this **.jar** file into the classpath doing:

```
C:\Projects\edi-sta\src>javac -cp ojdbc6.jar:. Main.java
```

So I think that it should mens that I have to compile the **Main.Java** class "importing" the classpath represented by the **ojdbc6.jar**.

It give me no error message and compile it but the problem is that when I try to perform the compiled **Main** class I obtain this error message:

```
C:\Projects\edi-sta\src>java Main
Hello World !!!
0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at Main.main(Main.java:21)

C:\Projects\edi-sta\src>
```

It can't see the **oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver** class definied into the **ojdbc6.jar** used as classpath at compile time.

Why I have this issue? What am I missing? How can I fix it?

**EDIT 1:**

I mooved my **Main.java** class into a package named **mainPkg**.

So I have the following situation in which I have also putted the **ojdbc6.jar** file:

```
C:\Projects\edi-sta\src\mainPkg>dir
 Il volume nell'unità C è OS
 Numero di serie del volume: 9414-E1F8

 Directory di C:\Projects\edi-sta\src\mainPkg

12/02/2015  14:18    <DIR>          .
12/02/2015  14:18    <DIR>          ..
12/02/2015  14:13             1.337 Main.class
12/02/2015  14:05             1.285 Main.java
11/02/2015  11:01         3.692.096 ojdbc6.jar
               3 File      3.694.718 byte
               2 Directory   4.861.566.976 byte disponibili
```

The **Main.class** file is created performing this command:

```
javac -cp ojdbc6.jar;. Main.java
```

I used also here the **;** separator because I am under Windows.

Now that I have create the **Main.class** file I try to perform this operation:

```
java -cp ojdbc6.jar;. Main
```

but I still obtain the **"impossible to find or load main class"** error message:

```
C:\Projects\edi-sta\src\mainPkg>javac -cp ojdbc6.jar;. Main.java

C:\Projects\edi-sta\src\mainPkg>java -cp ojdbc6.jar;. Main
Errore: impossibile trovare o caricare la classe principale Main

C:\Projects\edi-sta\src\mainPkg>
```

What am I missing? What is wrong?

Tnx

Answer (score 3):

You also need the jar in the classpath at runtime:

```
java -cp ojdbc6.jar:. Main
```

Otherwise, obviously, the JVM can't load the classes from the jar file: where would it find them?

Note that you should never use the default package. Get into the good habit of defining a package for all your classes.

Comment: I tryied to do as you explained but now I obtain the "impossible to find or load main class". What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? what is the content of the current directory (i.e. what is listed when you execute `ls` on Linux or `dir` on Windows)?

Comment: I am using Windows. The directory contains the Main.class, Main.java and the ojdbc6.jar files

Comment: On Windows, the separator is `;`, not `:`. So the command is `java -cp ojdbc6.jar;. Main`.

Comment: Still don't work. I have added some detailed informations at the end of my original post

Comment: Is your class in the package `mainPkg`? If so, you should be compiling and running from the `src` directory. To compile: `javac -cp mainPkg\ojdbc6.jar mainPkg\Main.java`. To run: `java -cp mainPkg\ojdbc6.jar;. mainPkg.Main`. But jar files shouldn't be in the source directories. And you should use the `-d` option to specify a directory other than the current one for class files. The classpath must contain jar files and directories that constitute the root of the package tree.

Answer (score 1):

You need the external JAR in the CLASSPATH at runtime, too.  Add the same -cp argument when you run.